# Enable UI virtualization on a TreeView in C#, programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, virtualization

Is it possible to enable UI virtualization on a programmatically created TreeView?

I want to do the same as this:

```
<TreeView VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling">
```

But on a TreeView that I created on-the-fly in C#.

Thanks!

Comment: **Don't create or manipulate UI elements in procedural code in WPF. That's what XAML is for.**

Comment: The interface is very dynamic so I can't put it all in the Xaml unfortunately :(

Comment: yes you can do "dynamic" interfaces in XAML using proper DataBinding. creating/manipulating UI elements is discouraged due to being an inconvenient technique due to the complexity of the Visual Tree. Post a screenshot of what you need, and a sample of the `data` you're using to build the UI and I can tell you the proper way to do it in WPF.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try this:

```
myTreeView.SetValue(VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingProperty, true);
myTreeView.SetValue(VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationModeProperty, VirtualizationMode.Recycling);
```

But of course HighCore is right ..

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by using [DependencyObject.SetValue Method (DependencyProperty, Object)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597473(v=vs.110).aspx) of the TreeView to set the attached property programmatically

`VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizingProperty` and `VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationModeProperty`

```
myTreeView.SetValue(VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizingProperty, true);
myTreeView.SetValue(VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationModeProperty, VirtualizationMode.Recycling);
```

**Another approach is to call the static methods**

```
VirtualizingStackPanel.SetIsVirtualizing(myTreeView, true);
VirtualizingStackPanel.SetVirtualizationMode(myTreeView, VirtualizationMode.Recycling);
```